# Generic and cast in java

Tags: java, generics, casting

suppose i have the following code

```
E[] arrayVar = (E[])new Object[1];// It causes a compiler warning
```

the question is, in what situation when the code will cause a run time error,

Comment: how can i accept answers? sorry i am still new here,

Comment: Click the check mark next to your favorite answer. Don't forget to upvote good answers too.

Comment: okay, thx, i have checked the mark on the best answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code will only cause a runtime error if you try to assign the result to the reified type of `E`:

```
createArray(); // no exception
String[] arr = createArray(); // causes ClassCastException

public static <E> E[] createArray() {
    return (E[]) new Object[1];
}
```

The safe way to create generic arrays is with the use of [`Array.newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29):

```
public static <E> E[] createArray(Class<E> component) {
    return (E[]) Array.newInstance(component, 1);
}
```

This method will not cause a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: This is the best answer here.

Comment: so, instead of using Object type, Array.newIstance is a better solution since it won't cause classCastException, thx, your answer has helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

to expand LastStar007's Answer

The problem with that statement is that java cannot determine the type of object E until runtime. also unfortunately, java does not provide a simple way to determine the type of a specified object (getClass() does not work for this).

your best bet (if it is numerical data) would be to check against the maximum of each mnemonic or for character data, check against the storage size per a character. yes it sounds tedious, but java has no typeinfo, like C++ which would make things a lot easier

Answer (score -2):

It will never cause a run-time error because it will always cause a compile-time error. An `Object` cannot be down-cast to an `E`, and therefore an `Object[]` cannot be down-cast to an `E[]`. Beyond that, you can't create an array of type `E` because the class has no idea what the type of `E` is at compile-time.

Comment: okay, i got your point, so when will it cause a compile time error? since i only got a compile warning message

Comment: I'm trying your code right now, and I'm getting errors. Can you post the rest of the method?

Comment: unfortunately, i havent tried it myself, i got the code from tutorials and it said that it will cause a compiler warning, still learning more about generics

Comment: Not a warning, but an error. To learn more about generics, here's the official Java trail: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: This does not cause a compilation error, it merely causes an unchecked cast warning.

Comment: I'm doing his single line of code in the main. Since he did not specify location otherwise, even after I asked, I assume that's where he wants it. Experience and intuition would lead me to believe otherwise, but I'm saying that when I execute only that line of code, I get errors, not warnings.

Comment: @LastStar007 That's because you did not define `E` as a type variable in either the class or the method.